# Scale data upon WCS request?

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, wcs, scale-factor

I am serving a set of GeoTiffs through GeoServer.
In order to save disk space I have multiplied my original 32 bit floating point data by a factor 1000 and then rounded to the nearest integer, so I could save the data as 16 bit integer GeoTiffs.
This is all fine for a WMS service, as GeoServer applies an appropriate color map.

But later on I want to set up a WCS service as well, allowing the user to download the data itself. Is there a way to let the WCS service rescale the data (so in my case divide by 1000.) when replying to a WCS requests?

I have looked for scaling options online, but only found things related to scaling the spatial resolution rather than the data values.

Comment: For WCS scaling look at http://www.opengis.net/doc/IS/WCS_scaling_extension/1.0, it is though I think only axes related and you want range set.  There's http://www.opengis.net/doc/IS/WCS-service-extension-range-
subsetting/1.0 but I don't think you want subsetting.

Comment: Thank you, nmtoken. That is interesting documentation. Indeed does not seem to give me a solution for my problem, but informative nontheless.

Comment: So the question you're asking is not about standard WCS operations, and perhaps about vendor specific options that geoserver offers on top of the WCS standard